# UIBarButtonItem custom view not displaying properly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'm trying to make an audio player, and have a toolbar on bottom. I programmatically add a barbutton item with a `UIImageView` as it's `customView` property, but when the image displays it is barely on screen:
[image]
the image is `Pause@2x.png`, is `40x40` pixels, and this is how I add the button

```
UIBarButtonItem *flex1, *flex2;
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause@2x.png"]];
self.play = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:iv];
[self.play setAction:@selector(pauseButtonClicked:)];
flex1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
flex2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[self.bar setItems:@[flex1, _play, flex2]];
```

`Pause.png`
[image]
`Pause@2x.png`
[image]

Comment: There is no point calling `setAction:` on a UIBarButtonItem created with `initWithCustomView`. It is not a button; it leaves touch handling entirely to the custom view. (The docs are quite clear on this point.)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to change the toolbar's height later in the code, removing that line fixed it.